How to setup Local NTP server in Ubuntu
I have completed all the necessary configuration steps to set up my system to synchronize its time with a local NTP server. However, despite my efforts, the system continues to connect to an external time server instead of the local one, which is not what I want. Here's the situation:
When I run the ntpq -p command, it shows that the system is still syncing with external servers instead of the local NTP server.
In the /etc/ntp.conf file, I've added the following lines to point to the local time source:
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 3
These entries are intended to make the system sync with its own clock (i.e., the localhost), and set the stratum level for the local clock to 3, which is a typical configuration for a system acting as its own NTP server.
The server 127.127.1.0 configuration is meant to instruct the system to sync with its local clock. This is used for cases where the system is acting as its own time server, rather than syncing with external NTP servers.
However, despite this, the system still attempts to sync with an external time server instead of the local one.
I have setup allow ufw 123/udp as well. I do not have systems-timesyncd installed to make any conflicts. I am setting this NTP service on my edge computer intel NUC. I want to setup a local NTP service on my edge computer that's it.
Any help would be appreciated
Additionally, when I tried using systemd-timesyncd:
sudo systemctl status systems-timesyncd command shows, active and running, but the status in Idle, and is timed out, waiting for reply.

Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s to format them.

ntpq -p means that you are using openntp for serving time. Ubuntu recommends  Chrony. You mix the NTP server and client. I don't understand what the role of the edge server is. If it's the NTP server than you should configure that server on the client, I'd stay away from using 127.127 until you have setup a clock that is disciplined. Syncing to your local clock does not make sense. It is already set to the time it thinks it is. Anyway switch to Chrony as it's easier to setup. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/how-to-serve-the-network-time-protocol-with-chrony

Thank you for your suggestions.  I will give a try using chrony.
